# Check if date is within a given timeframe

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I need to check if a date falls within a certain range.

I suppose I need the function to look something like this:

```
If Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") - 2 days <= sc3 <= Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") Then
     sc3 = D
     Console.WriteLine(D)
End If
```

However, I don't actually know what to put for the first part (`Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") - 2 days`).

Basically I need to check if a date falls between the current date and 2 days before.

Comment: Is this question about VBScript or VB6? They're two different languages.

Comment: It is neither, that looks to be VB.NET, which completely changes the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sample is VB.NET.

Ignoring time, this would be something like this:

```
Dim testDate As DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1,1)
Dim currDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date

If testDate <= currDate AndAlso testDate >= currDate - TimeSpan.FromDays(2) Then

'within range

End If
```

I didn't syntax check this, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Use the docs for [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb7z8yf9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to understand/experiment with:

```
Option Explicit

Dim dtToday : dtToday = Date
Dim nDiff
For nDiff = -3 To +3
    Dim dtTest : dtTest = DateAdd("d", nDiff, dtToday)
    Dim nDiff2 : nDiff2 = DateDiff("d", dtToday, dtTest)
    Dim bInR   : bInR   = -2 <= nDiff2 And 0 >= nDiff2 ' depends on your understand of "berween"
    WScript.Echo nDiff, dtTest, CStr(bInR)
Next
```

output:

```
-3 05.01.2014 False
-2 06.01.2014 True
-1 07.01.2014 True
0 08.01.2014 True
1 09.01.2014 False
2 10.01.2014 False
3 11.01.2014 False
```

(I choose to believe your VBScript tag)

Answer (score 0):

```
If Date.Now.AddDays(-2)<=sc3 AndAlso sc3<=Date.Now Then
    sc3 = D
    Console.WriteLine(D)
End If
```